# How to use OR filter condition in queryset?

Tags: python, django

How to add other filter condition in queryset?

In general, I only can filter with one condition like bellow:

```
queryset = PhysicalServerTask.objects.filter(task_status=TASK_STATUS.GOOD)
```

Can we filter with another condition like `and`?

I want to filter the `tast_status` equals `TASK_STATUS.GOOD` or `TASK_STATUS.WELL`.

How to do with that?

I know I can filter `TASK_STATUS.GOOD` and `TASK_STATUS.WELL`, then merge them. But if there is a better way to access that?

Comment: Can't we just do `PhysicalServerTask.objects.filter(task_status__in=[TASK_STATUS.GOOD, TASK_STATUS.WELL])` ?(Keyword argument queries – in filter(), etc. – are “AND”ed together. If you need to execute more complex queries (for example, queries with OR statements), you can use Q objects.)

Comment: You shouldn't call this AND, it's more like OR.

Comment: @wim yes, yes. my mistake, I want to write OR, I get dizzy giddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more condition for the `.filter` function. It should be;

```
PhysicalServerTask.objects.filter(
task_status__in=[TASK_STATUS.GOOD, TASK_STATUS.WELL])
```

Comment: The first way will not work (you can not specify the same keyword argument twice in Python).  Second way looks ok.