# How to filter for my requirement?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a requirement:

in my filter, I want to filter like bellow:

```
messages = Message.objects.filter(to_user=user or from_user=user).all()
```

I mean if the `to_user==user` or `from_user==user` all be queried out.

I found the bellow related post:

[How to use OR filter condition in queryset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161080/how-to-use-or-filter-condition-in-queryset)

But this is one params, you see this is different between my requirement scenario.

Comment: Look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567831/how-to-perform-or-condition-in-django-queryset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Q objects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), that allows complex lookups.

```
 from django.db.models import Q

 messages = Message.objects.filter(Q(to_user=user) | Q(from_user=user))
```

Comment: @fanhualuojin  if this helps, you can Accept this answer